# Divergence-free constraint for a boundary integral equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, potential-theory

Consider the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\operatorname{curl} \operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u} = 0 \qquad B \cup (\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \overline{B}) \\
c_1 (\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{n})^{+} - c_2 (\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{n})^{-} = \xi \times \mathbf{n} \qquad \partial B  \\
(\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf n)^{+} =  (\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf n)^{-}\qquad \partial B \\
(\mathbf u \times \mathbf n)^{+} =  (\mathbf u \times \mathbf n)^{-}\qquad \partial B,
\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{*}
$$

where $c_1, c_2$ are given positive real constants, $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a given vector and $B$ the unit ball. Since the first equation is formally equivalent to the couple $\vec{\Delta} \mathbf u =0, \ \operatorname{div} \mathbf u =0$, and the last two mean that $\mathbf u$ is continuous accross the interface, the idea is to seek for a (single) layer potential represention of the form:

$$ \mathbf u (x) = \int_{\partial B} \Psi(x,y) \mathbf a(y) \, ds(y) $$

with $\Psi(x,y) = \frac{1}{4\pi|x-y|}$. From $[1]$ we know that if $\mathbf a \in C^0(\partial B)$ with $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf n = 0$, then the jump relationship

$$ (\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{n})(x)^{\pm} = \int_{\partial B} \operatorname{curl}_x [\Psi(x,y) \mathbf a(y)] \times \mathbf n(x) \, ds(y) \pm \frac{\mathbf{a}(x)}{2} = \left( M \mathbf a \pm \frac{\mathbf a}{2} \right)(x) $$

holds. Explointing this formula, the jump condition \eqref{1} yields an integral equation of the form:

$$ \widetilde M \mathbf a + \mathbf a = \lambda, $$

where $\lambda = \xi \times \mathbf n$ (up to a constant) and $\widetilde M$ is just a rescaled version of $M$.

Now the Fredholm-Riesz theory gives us that $\widetilde M + I$ is bijective (in a space of continuous tangential vector fields) with bounded inverse and thus we obtain solvability of the integral equation.
The problem is now that we can't say that $\operatorname{div}_{\tau} \mathbf a = 0$, and hence that $\operatorname{div} \mathbf u = 0$, so that rather than \eqref{1}, we have solved the same problem for the vector Laplacian. Is there a way to fix this argument in such a way that we can guarantee that the solution is divergence-free?

**References:**

$[1]$: David Colton and Rainer Kress. *Integral equation methods in scattering theory*, SIAM, 2013.

Comment: Is the equation as stated not solvable by itself?

Comment: Why? I can't see it...

Comment: That is my question: this is an integral equation, of the form (Id+K)a = F, so is $K$ compact, and does $Id+K$ have a kernel? 
You are implying that you can change $div_\tau a$ at will, by your question.

Comment: Ok now I see your point. I will investigate and peharps update the question. Thank you